# Usage: adding an up/back button to an Android toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, back

Is it recommended or discouraged? I've found two different guidelines from Google:

**Guideline One:**
Back navigation is how users move backward through the history of screens they previously visited. All Android devices provide a Back button for this type of navigation, **so your app should not add a Back button to the UI**.

**Guideline Two:**
The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens. For instance, if screen A displays a list of items, and selecting an item leads to screen B (which presents that item in more detail), **then screen B should offer an Up button that returns to screen A.**

So what's best practice? To include or not to include?

Comment: I have also been very confused about this, since these two guidelines - BOTH found in Googles developer docs - stand contrary to each other. I wonder if they could/should remove the first one since they want people to follow material design as much as possible now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is best to use it !
[As per the material design docs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar), it says:

> The nav icon at the left side of the app bar can be:
>
> ```
> A control to open a navigation drawer.
> An up arrow for navigating upward through your app’s hierarchy.
> Omitted entirely if no navigation is required from this screen.
> ```

And the [navigation in history docs](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html):

> The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological
>   order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked
>   with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between
>   screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.
>
> When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of
>   the current screen, pressing the Back button has the same result as
>   pressing an Up button—this is a common occurrence. However, unlike the
>   Up button, which ensures the user remains within your app, the Back
>   button can return the user to the Home screen, or even to a different
>   app.

And of course, if you check almost all Google Apps, they include the Up navigation button in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, Leonardo. My reputation is too low to mark you up, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help !